# How to see all XtraChart Pie Labels

Tags: charts, devexpress, pie-chart

there are a possibility to see all XtraChart Pie Labels? Exemple:

[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:

1. Experiment with the [SeriesLabelBase.ResolveOverlappingMode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument7042) and [SeriesLabelBase.ResolveOverlappingMinIndent](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsSeriesLabelBase_ResolveOverlappingMinIndenttopic) . Try setting the ResolveOverlappingMode to "Default" for example.
2. Increase chart placement area and/or reduce chart size by adjusting the MinAllowedSizePercentage property:

   <charts:PieSeriesView MinAllowedSizePercentage="80">
3. Try changing the [indent between labels](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q381522) like:

   <dxc:PieSeries2D.Label>
               <dxc:SeriesLabel RenderMode="RectangleConnectedToCenter" Indent="40" />
   </dxc:PieSeries2D.Label>

Let me know if it worked.